# Next.js 14: Why won't revalidatePath() revalidate this page?

Tags: next.js, vercel, next.js13

I have this website that displays events in a calendar and an event page for each event.

#### URLs and paths

These are my paths and URLs.

- Event page url: `/nb/arrangement/en-skole-for-alle`
- Event page path:
  `/[lang]/arrangement/[slug]/page`
- Events calendar url: `/nb/kalender`
- Events calendar path: `/[lang]/kalender/page`

#### Revalidate function

This is the relevant part of my revalidate function. It works, I see that it's called correctly. I'm here just desperately trying every permutation to see if my syntax is wrong.

```
 .with({ _type: "event" }, (doc) => {
  console.log("/[lang]/arrangement");
  revalidatePath("/nb/kalender");
  revalidatePath("/nb/kalender/page");
  revalidatePath("/nb/kalender/page", "page");
  revalidatePath("/[lang]/kalender/page", "page");
  revalidatePath("/[lang]/kalender", "page");
  revalidatePath("/[lang]/kalender", "layout");
  revalidatePath("/nb/kalender", "layout");
  revalidatePath("/[lang]/kalender");
  revalidatePath(`/nb/arrangement/${doc.slug.current}`);
  revalidatePath(`/en/arrangement/${doc.slug.current}`);
  console.log("/[lang]/kalender");
  revalidatePath("/en/calendar", "page");
  console.log("/[lang]");
  revalidatePath("/nb", "page");
  revalidatePath("/en", "page");
  revalidatePath("/", "layout");
  return Response.json({ revalidated: true, now: Date.now() });
})
```

#### The problem

The issue here is that the url/path of the single event gets revalidated correctly (`/nb/arrangement/en-skole-for-alle`), but `/nb/kalender` won't be revalidated no matter what I try.

Locally (when building and then `pnpm start`), it correctly revalidates both pages, but when deployed to Vercel, it won't revalidate this one page.

**What is the issue? Any tips on what I can try out?**

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.

My issue was actually a missing `<Suspense>` boundary around `useSearchParams()`, which made the ["Entire page deopted into client-side rendering"](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deopted-into-client-rendering). Which then disabled the static page generation and revalidation for this route.

Very sneaky issue to figure ut.